# Event to take control's text via event args

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, textbox, decimal

What is the event I should subscribe to in order to get `TextBox`'s `Text` in the event args?

I've tried `PreviewTextInput`, but if input string is, for example, "122." the box's (see code) text is without the dot but eventArgs.Text is "." and the input string validating successfully and TextBox.Text is "122..". What I want to do is to validate if the input string is decimal by calling `decimal.TryParse`.

```
private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    var box = sender as TextBox;
    if (box == null) return;

    eventArgs.Handled = !ValidationUtils.IsValid(box.Text + eventArgs.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this:

```
private void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    var text = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);
    decimal number;
    if (!decimal.TryParse(text, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out number))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: just need to make sure you either disable copy-paste or handle that explicitly as paste event will bypass this validation

Comment: have you tried this code? I'm getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException at this line `var text = textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);`

Comment: @sega Sure. It works fine for me. And of course the handler is attached to the `PreviewTextInput` event.

Comment: @Clemens, a little addition..the value binded to text property of textbox is of type decimal?, not decimal. Could it cause any problems?

Comment: "is of type decimal?, not decimal" What does that mean?

Comment: Ah ok, I understand. I can't see how that would affect the above code.