# OnPreviewTextInput event: how *would* result look like?

Tags: c#, wpf, events

When I am in the `OnPreviewTextInput` event, I have access the the text *before* the change and the new character. Is there a property that will tell me what the full text will look like if the input is not changed?

I am restricting input to numbers within boundaries. So I don't really care what the current input is. It is more interesting to me what the whole number will look like to check whether the number after the input violates the boundaries (= is illegal an cannot be processed).

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16820101/1136211)? Not sure what you mean by "how the result would look like". As it wouldn't change it would look like before.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `textBox.Text.Insert(textBox.CaretIndex, e.Text);` was what I was looking for, but I looked in the wrong place. I was looking for an object to hold that info.

Comment: Thank you! Once again... :)

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the suggested code fails if the user as selected some text with the mouse before entering the new digit. It is not enough just to insert the new digit, one must first remove the highlighted text.

[image]

Entering a 9 should result in 12945. But Text.Insert(CaretIndex, e.Text) returns 129345. The correct code would be:

```
Text.Remove(CaretIndex, SelectionLength).Insert(CaretIndex, e.Text)
```

Or in C# 8

```
Text[..CaretIndex] + e.Text + Text[(CaretIndex + SelectionLength)..]
```